# Select value from one REST call for another REST call

Tags: rest, variables, powershell

I am trying to using PowerShell to build out my script to run few restful GET calls. And I was able to do it But I'm running into a variable issue. let me explain.

Below is my GET call. as you can see where `reportid12345` is a dynamic variable.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://website.com/reportid12345/?reportdownload"&"auth_token=2a31df31ads3fw -OutFile C:\testdailyoutput.csv
```

Now to get a list of dynamic report IDs I have to make below call:

```
$dailyreportid = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://website.com/allreports?fields=id"&"auth_token=32sd1f85w2d32
```

and the output is below:

```
data
----
{@{id=1000}, @{id=1115}}
```

and if I type `$dailyreportid.data` then the output is:

```
  id
  --
1000
1115
```

So my question is: how can I use variable to make my report download call to use variable from the second call? But to select the largest number of the report ID or the bottom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$dailyreportid = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://website.com/allreports?fields=id&auth_token=32sd1f85w2d32"

$id = $dailyreportid.data.id | sort | select -last 1

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://website.com/reportid$id/?reportdownload&auth_token=2a31df31ads3fw" -OutFile C:\testdailyoutput.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked like a charm. the second step is the key!!